# Is it possible to change a row color based on time and whether a cell is empty or not?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that has 2 sheets (Sheet1 and Sheet2). Sheet1 is connected to a form to receive responses, while Sheet2 is just a copy of information from Sheet1 with sorting and formatting using the ImportRange function. The form responses only uses column A:G while column H and I will be filled in later.

After a response is received the color of the row where the the response is will change to Yellow. After column H is filled, the row color will change to Blue, and after I is filled, turns to Green.

Is it possible or not using Conditional Formatting or Google App Script that if after a response is received (row turns Yellow), if within 5 minutes there's no data entered into column H, the row for column A:G changes to "Red" and will only changes to "Blue" after H is filled in?

So far, I have only tried using Conditional Formatting where I used the `Custom Formula is... =$G2<>""` condition.

Apart from that someone suggested using the following code on App Script(using differences between Unixtime) but I couldn't get it to work properly (it doesn't turn "Red" after 10 minutes, it just stay as yellow):

```
function myFunction() {  
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange();

  var unixStart = new Date(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);  
  var nowDate = ss.getCell(2, 13).getValue() - (unixStart * 86400);
  var rows = ss.getLastRow();

  for (var i = 2; i <= rows; i++){
   var checkTime = ss.getCell(i, 7).getValue() - (unixStart * 86400);    
    if (nowDate - checkTime < 600000){
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange(i, 1, 1, 7).setBackground("yellow");
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. _if within 5 minutes there's no data entered into column H..._ How critical/negotiable is the 5 minute adjustment period? For example, a time-driven trigger might be an option but even if set for every 5 minutes, there is still a chance that a response might not be processed for 9 minutes. You could reduce the time period but depending on the number of responses received, you would need to be conscious of any quota issues.

Comment: Preferably 5 minutes after a response is received, and column H is still not filled in, then the row changes to red. If after 5 minutes passed, but there is already data in H column, then there is no need to change to row color anymore. This is used to alert someone whether or not H is already filled in or not.

Comment: Something like this might be more simply accomplished without Apps Script, sticking with conditional formatting alone. If memory serves, Forms produces a timestamp for when the data is entered into the form. You can use this and add 5 minutes to it (`timestamp + 5/24/60`), and if `NOW()` is greater than this _timestamp + 5 minutes_ and column H isn't filled yet, then change the color to red. Your only problem is that `NOW()` isn't going to update automatically, so you will need to change it in _File > Spreadsheet settings > Calculation > Recalculation > **On change and every minute**_.

Comment: I had the the thought to use this as well, but I am unable to come up with the correct condition for Conditional Formatting. Would you have any idea on what the custom should be? Plus, because I'm using a different sheet to keep the formatting of the responses, it seem like the cell won't move together with the information on column A:I.

Comment: [This is what I've got.](https://i.imgur.com/2tN4lpM.png) The custom formula here is applied from C2:C11: `=AND(NOW()>B2,D2="")`. I'm not sure what you mean by "the cell won't move together with the information", could you please clarify that further?

Comment: In this formula is B2 the (timestamp + 5/24/60), while D2=" " is for column H? Well, because I want the row from A:G to be colored whenever it's over 5 minutes. Therefore I thought the formula would need to be copied down each row. But, whenever a new response comes in, only the columns A:I will move down a row because I'm using IMPORTRANGE from the actual response sheet in order to keep the formatting for new responses. Columns J:Z doesn't move downwards with A:I.

Comment: Yes, that's correct (B2 is the _timestamp + 5/24/60_ and D2 is column H). Sorry for not clarifying. You can use that same conditional formatting across multiple columns if you freeze the column reference. For example, `=AND(NOW()>$B2,$D2="")`, applied through columns A:G. As for how your data comes in, I believe that Forms adds new responses to the bottom of the sheet rather than the top. Are you, by any chance, sorting in reverse order so that newest responses are at the top? If that's the case, you might need to disable that. It's not possible for cells to move with a dynamic imported range.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a must for me to sort by newest first. However, I believe I did managed to work it out using your earlier suggestion. I didn't know about the Timestamp + 5/24/60 formula. Using that, I simply just used a NOW()<B2, and made it so it will only be Green for the first 5 minute, then goes Red after that.

Comment: @James I like the non-script solution. May I suggest that you (or Jme Sekaiichi) write up and submit an answer. IMHO, notwithstanding the useful comments, it's always easier to see the outcome summarised in an answer.

Comment: @Tedinoz Thanks for the suggestion. I've written up the answer now rather than a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can color cells based on time without having to use Apps Script, which keeps your file simpler.

For your use case, you can do this by controlling your limit with a helper column with this formula:

```
=time_stamp + 5/24/60
```

where `time_stamp` is the timestamp produced by Forms. This will add 5 minutes to when the form is submitted automatically.

You can then use this new column as one of the rules in conditional formatting for the cells in the range `A:G`, with this formula:

```
=AND(NOW()>time_stamp_plus_5, $H2="", $I2="")
```

and set the fill color to red. This will change all of the cells within `A:G`, which meet the following 3 conditions, to red color:

1. The current time as determined by `NOW()` is after 5 minutes after the form submission.
2. Column H is empty.
3. Column I is empty.

You can then add the additional rules as usual for the yellow, blue, and green coloring:

- Yellow: `=$time_stamp<>""`
- Blue: `=$H2<>""`
- Green: `=$I2<>""`

The only hiccup is that, by default, `NOW()` only recalculates when a change is made on the form. You can tell it to recalculate automatically every minute by going to *File > Spreadsheet settings > Calculation > Recalculation* and set it to "On change and every minute". This will make sure that `NOW()` always updates every minute.

---

As you stated in the comments, there is a confounding issue for your setup with the way you sorted the newest form submissions first. I would suggest submitting a separate question for that issue to see whether some workarounds can be made for your setup.